# My application is not successfully logging in to the web service

Tags: java, android, rest

I tried using the class found on [this](http://lukencode.com/2010/04/27/calling-web-services-in-android-using-httpclient/) site to implement a way to login through a web service. Whenever I try to log in on my test program Ive set the output after the login attempt to "response". The program stalls for about a second, then outputs an empty string. Is there any way to see if my application is even trying to log in? Or even succesfully connecting to the internet?

Code snippet below:

```
private RestClient restClient = new RestClient("https://service....");
...
private void LoginCheck()
{

    restClient.AddParam("username", username);
    restClient.AddParam("password", userpass);

    try {
        restClient.Execute(RequestMethod.POST);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    String response = restClient.getResponse();
    Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, response, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Comment: Have you added INTERNET permission to your manifest?

Comment: Yeah. And after I did that the program would stall for a moment before returning.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to do HTTPPost, which you can do in this way, it works for me.

```
   try {
    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();  
    String postURL = "https://service....";
    HttpPost post = new HttpPost(postURL);
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", "foo"));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", "bar"));
        UrlEncodedFormEntity ent = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params,HTTP.UTF_8);
        post.setEntity(ent);
        HttpResponse responsePOST = client.execute(post);  
        HttpEntity resEntity = responsePOST.getEntity();  
        if (resEntity != null) {    
            String response = EntityUtils.toString(resEntity));
        }
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```